# Change hive loaded into HKCU?

Tags: windows-registry

Does anyone know of a scriptable way to change what hive is loaded into HKCU? There is a particular program that I need to run on startup that checks values in HKCU. However, I do not want to create a separate account or have it use the builtin Administrator account.

Comment: What do you think will happen when you log in after your user registry hive was replaced?

Comment: Can't you just set the key/value that the program wants in your current HKCU?

Answer (score 2):

First things first.

The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU)` is a copy of the `HKEY_USERS (HKU)` of the user actually logged in a Windows session...

You can't load in HKCU somethings different than the keys and values of HKU

E.G. `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3681983559-1923665867-785417408-1007`
     If the user with this ID is actually logged the HKCU IS
     a copy of the first one (say a "virtual" copy)

If you modify a key in HKU this is reflected in HKCU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. And if it is, it's a bad idea.

Consider this.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Run\
```

defines an item that should be run when the user logs in. You load that into your primary profile. But that profile has no access rights to the element defined in the registry. So it must fail. Or worse, it runs and deletes something of your primary profile.

This is a single, obvious conflict that will happen if you attempt this. I am sure there would be hundreds.

I could come up with a couple more points why this is a horrible idea. I'm sure you're approaching your problem the wrong way (or I simply misunderstood you).